# Function with arrays not working

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

I need to make a program with three functions.

The main function should call the second function passing it the array as the first argument and the number of elements in the array as the second argument.

The second function is passed in an array and the number of elements in the array. The function should get 8 names from the user and return the number of names read back to main. Use the return statement to do this.

After the array is filled by the second function, main should then call a third function passing it the array as the first argument and the value returned by the second function as the second argument.

The third function should display the names from the array on separate lines on the computer screen. The third function is passed in an array as the first parameter. The second parameter is the number of elements in the array to be displayed.

The main function has an array of 10 elements. The second function is passed that array of 10 elements but only reads in 8 elements. The number read in by the second function is returned back to main. Main then passes the array and the value returned back from the second function to the third function.

My code up to this point is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
// get the names and store them in the array
int const arraySize(10);
int names = 8;          
string array[arraySize];

// send to second function
recievenames(array, arraySize);

// send to third function
displaynames(array, 8);

return 0;
}


int recievenames(string array[], int arraySize)
{
int names = 0;

// Get names.
for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter name " << (count + 1) << " of 8: ";
    cin >> array[count];

    if (count < 8)
    {
        names++;
    }
}
// Display amount of names entered.
cout << names << " received.";
}

void displaynames(string array[], int names)
{
// Display names entered in array.
for (int count = 0; count < names; count++)
{
    cout << array[count] << endl;
}
}
```

For some reason it isn't working can someone tell me why?

Comment: Define "not working". Compile time error? Run time problem?

Comment: Your code is not going to get compiled since the functions are not declared before using them. You should either declare the functions before main or type in the complete function deceleration before the main

Comment: "It isn't working" - that's because it doesn't compile. The compiler hasn't a clue your functions even exist at the point you're calling them in `main()`. You at least need prototypes, or move them *before*  `main`. And `recievenames` says it returns a value. Either provide one or change the result type to `void`. You may also consider using the `arraySize` you passed rather than hard-code a magic 8  in the read-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do a foward declartion of the function prototypes `recievenames()` and `displaynames()` and place them before `main()` . Then you can define and embody the functions after main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// declare function prototypes
int recievenames(string array[], int arraySize);
void displaynames(string array[], int names);




int main()
{
// get the names and store them in the array
int const arraySize(10);
int names = 8;          
string array[arraySize];

// send to second function
recievenames(array, arraySize);

// send to third function
displaynames(array, 8);

return 0;
}

//define functions
int recievenames(string array[], int arraySize)
{
int names = 0;

// Get names.
for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter name " << (count + 1) << " of 8: ";
    cin >> array[count];

    if (count < 8)
    {
        names++;
    }
    return 0;
}
// Display amount of names entered.
cout << names << " received.";
}

void displaynames(string array[], int names)
{
// Display names entered in array.
for (int count = 0; count < names; count++)
{
    cout << array[count] << endl;
}
}
```